# Subdomains on AWS

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-ec2, dns, subdomain, amazon-route53

I wanted just to double check this since my friend asked me to be double check this. We have a domain and the customer support is kinda hard to work with, so it would be easier if we could do this on "Amazon side".

We have a EC2 instance, and want to have another separate one on a different domain, subdomain.example.com. That subdomain would be handled by the separate instance.

We are currently using elastic IP for one instance, Route 53 to route requests from Amazon DNS to the specific instance, and on the name register we have set up the route 53 name servers.

Is there a way to do this via AWS/Route 53 or some other tool, or the subdomains have to be explicitly handled on the name register?

Thanks!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

DNS handles mapping for subdomains. If you ware using Route 53, you would set it up there.

Comment: Just to add to datasage's answer, you can have an EIP attached to the EC2 instance and an A record in the R53 recordset that points to that specific IP (the public hostname would change after a reboot, that's why I recommend using an elastic IP)

Comment: How exactly would I do that?

I already have those records there, but subdomains wont work so far. Do I need to create a new hosted zone? Or? www.example.com doesn't work, although there is a CNAME record for that pointing to the same IP as example.com with type A record, so it seems that those xxx.example.com are not being caught by the Route 53.

Comment: If www.example.com and example.com resolve to the IP (something you can verify with dig), then your problem is not with DNS, but instead with your web server configuration. With name based virtual hosting, you need to specify each domain (and subdomain) you want your site to respond to.

Comment: I managed to achieve this, route53 was able to handle this at the end :)

Answer (score 1):

I would say that you don't need EIP.
Just register EC2 instance public DNS (ec2-54-00-000-169.compute-1.amazonaws.com) as CNAME record in your Route53 zone.
Using CNAME is better than IP address. In that case your name will be resolved to private IP address if you are resolving it from inside AWS network or to public IP address if from outside AWS network.

Comment: Thank you for the contribution, I have managed to resolve this earlier.

Answer (score 0):

You can even try [Arecord](http://www.arecord.net/) a free service to avoid zone apex issue

Answer (score 0):

If I understand the problem I think that you don't have to use the route 53 service.
You can just point both of the domains to your elastic IP and create a virtual server.

You can create a new virtual server using the httpd.conf found at /etc/httpd/conf .

Just add to the end of the file something like that:

```
NameVirtualHost *:80

<VirtualHost *:80>
    DocumentRoot /var/www/html/SomeDomain
    ServerName somedomain.com
    ServerAlias www.somedomain.com
</VirtualHost>
<VirtualHost *:80>
    DocumentRoot /var/www/html/SomeDomain2
    ServerName somedomain2.com
    ServerAlias www.somedomain2.com
</VirtualHost>
```